# A simple way to write large elseif statements in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm getting post values from an emailer form and I set all the option values to numbers and I'm trying to convert them to their actual strings to send in an email.  I need to make this code easier to use.

```
if ($subject == "1") {
$sub = "General Questions"; 
} elseif($subject == "2") {
$sub = "Membership";
} elseif($subject == "3") {
    $sub = "Club Fees";
} elseif($subject == "4") {
    $sub = "Proshop &amp; Lessons";
} elseif($subject == "5") {
    $sub = "Events"; 
} elseif($subject == "6") {
    $sub == "Leagues &amp; Programs";
} elseif($subject == "7") {
    $sub == "Resturant &amp; Bar";
};
```

Maybe I could set the `value=''` to the actual values and skip this part all together.

Comment: Use a switch statement instead http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: after looking again it seems pointless to set a numerical key, why not use your value as the key ?

Comment: @Philip: Could be database mapping or limitation

Comment: @BradChristie seems to be retrieved from the db that way, however the actual output is what is required from what it seems, so simply <select name="subject"><option value="'.$v.'">'.$v.'</option></select>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not make an associative array?

```
$subs = array(
  1 => 'General Questions',
  2 => 'Membership',
  3 => 'Club Fees',
  4 => 'Proshop &amp; Lessons',
  // others.
);

$sub = isset($subs[$subject]) ? $subs[$subject] : 'Default Value';
```

Comment: +1, this looks like the best way to do it to me, but that's not an associative array. The keys are all numeric.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. Depends on perspective, it's still overriding default behavior of a 0-index array. ;-) (Also, associate can be in reference to "`$subject` becomes `$sub`")

Comment: I've always thought of associative as the keys having external meaning, which they do here(they map a number to a value). You couldn't renumber the keys, for example. I know my statement is a bit ambiguous, but I hope my point is made.

Answer (score 4):

One way to rewrite is to use the `switch` statement in PHP. You can [read more about it here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

Answer (score 3):

Use a `switch` statement, or map the potential outcomes to their respective values:

```
switch ( $subject ) {
  case 1:
    $sub = 'foo';
    break;
  case 2:
    $sub = 'bar';
    break;
}
```

Or

```
$values = array( "Foo", "bar" );
$sub = $values[ --$subject ];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?php
switch ($subject)
{
case "1":
  $sub = "General Questions";
  break;
case "2":
  $sub = "Membership";
  break;
case "3":
  $sub = "Club Fees";
  break;
case "4":
  $sub = "Proshop &amp; Lessons";
  break;
case "5":
  $sub = "Events";
  break;
case "6":
  $sub = "Leagues &amp; Programs";
  break;
case "6":
  $sub = "Resturant &amp; Bar";
  break;
default:
  $sub = "";
}
?>
```